# How do I uninstall Libreoffice Draw without uninstalling Libreoffice Impress?

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, uninstall, libreoffice

I have a desktop computer with Lubuntu Raring Ringtail 13.04. It runs pretty well, but this Linux distro includes some software that I don't use at all, such as Libreoffice Draw.

I don't know how to uninstall it properly. I've tried using synaptic and `apt-get purge` but both of them said that I have to unistall LibreOffice Impress in order to unistall Draw, and I don't want to do it because I use Impress for school homework a lot. I would like you to give me some ideas about how to unistall LibreOffice Draw without uninstalling Impress.

Comment: Have you considered that Impress does *depend* on Draw, and that is why you need to have Draw installed?

Comment: Actually it *does not*

Comment: @meskobalazs Well, the package does, if it's a bug, it's a bug :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to uninstall (purge), and then only load the meta-packages for the parts you want.

See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice

(look for 'Selective installation')

Answer (score 0):

You can can't. The `libreoffice-impress` package depends on `libreoffice-draw`.

See the output of:

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Depends}\n' libreoffice-impress | grep -oFe libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-draw
```